# Электроный журнал

Tags: php

Можно ли сделать простой электронный журнал на PHP, с списком класса и датой?

Comment: Можно. Причем как с mySQL, так и на файлах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, можно. Это стандартная веб-задача. Более того, если хорошо поискать в сети (php time-table) найдутся уже готовые журналы, которые потребуют небольшой доводки.

Для практических целей проще использовать Google Calendar или Google Docs.